# В чём может заключаться проблема при загрузке на beget своего сайта?

Tags: php, html, hosting

После добавления сайта на хостинг Beget выходит
"404 Page Not Found
The page you requested was not found." - прописанная в структуре сайта страница.
Выводит три ошибки:
GET http://s98995pt.beget.tech/
GET http://s98995pt.beget.tech/favicon.ico
Error: Promised response from onMessage listener went out of scope 3 ci.bg.pack.js:213:27. Как их можно исправить?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmrOn.jpg

Comment: Вам необходимо к сайту в пу прикрепить домен

Comment: Может не в ту папку залили?!

Comment: Домен прилинкован, все файлы сайта лежат в папке "public html"

Comment: данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что его следует адресовать в соответствующую техподдержку